# How can i submit a form and pop up an alert at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

(I'm using  ASP.NET, MVC 4 , C# , Bootstrap, Javascript.)

I have a form to upload files(multiple), and its works great, this is the form :

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose a filter:</td>
                    <td style="margin-bottom:auto">
                        @Html.DropDownList("filterProfile", (SelectList)ViewBag.FilterList)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>File:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="Files" id="Files" multiple /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        }
```

Because upload files may take a little bit of time i figure that a pop up alert that say that we processing your files would be nice, so i added an ID to the submit button in the form like this :

```
 <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="alertMe" value="Filter" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

As you can see the ID is 'alertMe'.

then i wrote this code in the JS file :

```
$(function () {
$('#alertMe').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#processAlert').slideDown();
});
```

});

that reefer to this section in my View(HTML) :

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" id="processAlert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" id="processAlert">&times;</button>
<strong>Processing...</strong> Upload files and Processing your request.
```

But now its only show the alert without submitting the file, if i take off the ID attribute of the submit button its works great...How can i make the submit button trigger two events ?

one event is the show the alert of processing the file.
and the other event is to post the files to method in the controller.

How can i do it ? if its possible...

**What i end up doing:**( IMoses Answer)

I just remove the "preventDefault" from the script.

Comment: Simply remove `e.preventDefault();` from the event handler. You are actively stopping the form from being submitted.

Comment: Mohse its works for me, when i remove the "preventDefualt" am i losing something here ?

Comment: No. What will happen is that your event handler will get executed and once its done it will continue bubbling the `click` event until a `submit` action will be triggered. Saves you the trouble of initiating the `submit` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a call to prevent default will prevent the form from submitting. So adding a call to submit your form will fix this.

```
$(function () {
$('#alertMe').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#processAlert').slideDown();
   $('form:first').submit();
});
```

Comment: the form still not submit... i try even changing the order of the line like this :
$('form:first').submit();
$('#processAlert').slideDown();

Still its just show the alert nothing more.